# Rails select query displaying all columns with odd formatting in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new to Rails and I've hit my first wall. Up until now I've been able to use Google for the answer. To be honest, I think part of the problem is that I'm unable to properly explain the problem.

My Rails Select query in the show.html.erb file is (1) displaying duplicate records and (2) displaying the data with odd formatting instead of plain text. I'll paste all code below to fully illustrate.

I have a User model that has_many :works

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, :works_attributes
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name
  validates_uniqueness_of :first_name, :last_name, :email, :case_sensitive => false

  has_many :works
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :works
```

Here is my work model, which belongs_to user

```
class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :work_name, :users_id

  belongs_to :user
end
```

And here is the users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @users }
end


end
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @works = @user.works.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
    end
  end
end
```

In my users show.html.erb view, I want to loop through the works that belong to a particular user. I setup the foreign key relationship with a user_id field to follow Rails convention. When the loop finds a work that belongs to the user, I want to display the work_name field.

```
<% if @user.works.any? %>
                    <% @user.works.each do |user| %>
                   <%= @user.works(:select => 'work_name') %>
                  <% end %>
                <% end %>
```

However, this is the output I'm seeing on the website when viewing /users/1/:

```
[#<Work id: 1, work_name: "WorkTest1", description: "I am the co-founder and CEO of WorkTest1, a website t...", created_at: "2013-02-12 00:33:19", updated_at: "2013-02-12 00:33:19", user_id: 1>, #<Work id: 2, work_name: "WorkTest2", description: "test", created_at: "2013-02-12 00:33:19", updated_at: "2013-02-12 00:33:19", user_id: 1>] [#<Work id: 1, work_name: "WorkTest1", description: "I am the co-founder and CEO of WorkTest1, a website t...", created_at: "2013-02-12 00:33:19", updated_at: "2013-02-12 00:33:19", user_id: 1>, #<Work id: 2, work_name: "WorkTest2", description: "test", created_at: "2013-02-12 00:33:19", updated_at: "2013-02-12 00:33:19", user_id: 1>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .each loop is not looping over Users but Work objects.

You should just be able to do:

```
<% @user.works.each do |work| %>
  <%= work.work_name %>
<% end %>
```

Also, since you are defining @work in the controller action you can reduce it to:

```
<% @works.each do |work| %>
  <%= work.work_name %>
<% end %>
```

You already have the work objects at your disposal. I don't think there is any reason to try to select anything else.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much. Follow up question so I understand this 100%. This simplified convention works for the If statement in the view as well, correct? I changed <% if @user.works.any? %> to <% if @works.any? %> and the data output seems to be the same.

Comment: Yep, in your scenario `@user.works` and `@works` are the same thing.